# From two arrays, get all elements that are in either array but not both using Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I have two arrays for example `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[5, 3, 2, 1]`.

How can I get all elements that are in either array but not both? (`[4, 5]`)

This is my code so far it works but I think there must be a better way...

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
    val b = arrayOf(5, 3, 1, 2)

    val list = arrayListOf<Int>() 
    for (item in a) {
        if(item !in b){
            list.add(item)
        }
    }
    for (item in b) {
        if(item !in a){
            list.add(item)
        }
    }

    print(list)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you converted your **arrays** to [**sets**](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-set/index.html) you could do something like this to get the disjunctive union, provided you do not need to preserve duplicate elements:

```
val a = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
val b = arrayOf(5, 3, 1, 2)
val aSet = a.toSet()
val bSet = b.toSet()
print((aSet - bSet).union(bSet - aSet)) // [4, 5]
```

Comment: note though that it won't preserve duplicate elements

Comment: @user2340612 I actually was going to remove duplicates anyway so this saves me a step :)

Comment: Whats with the downvote? Its basically the same as the other set answer?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you currently have, this is a quick improvement:

```
val list = a.filter { it !in b } + b.filter { it !in a }
```

For better performance though, introducing sets that you make the lookups in is a good idea:

```
val aSet = a.toSet()
val bSet = b.toSet()
val list = a.filter { it !in bSet } + b.filter { it !in aSet }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is two *subtract* operations:

```
a.subtract(b.toSet()) + b.subtract(a.toSet())
```